# Convert an array by maping with condition in JS

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have an Array which i'm getting from API response which is like:

```js
[
  {date: "2021-04-09T12:00",duration: 1,available: 1,booked: 0,product_id: 2390,date_format: "PM"},
  {date: "2021-04-09T22:00",duration: 1,available: 1,booked: 0,product_id: 2390,date_format: "PM"},
  {date: "2021-04-10T2:00",duration: 1,available: 1,booked: 0,product_id: 2390,date_format: "PM"},
  {date: "2021-04-10T22:00",duration: 1,available: 1,booked: 0,product_id: 2390,date_format: "AM"},
]
```

Now i have date value which is like `"2021-04-09"` i want to find the match this date from the array and get the time value only from the above array. Here's my expected output:

```js
[
  {date: "12:00",duration: 1,available: 1,booked: 0,product_id: 2390,date_format: "PM"},
  {date: "22:00",duration: 1,available: 1,booked: 0,product_id: 2390,date_format: "PM"},
]
```

I just want the time part of the date. How can i do that?

Comment: Are there multiple such `date` values on the basis of which you want to filter your array ?

Comment: That depends. It could be one or multiple too. @LakshyaThakur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like below might work with `reduce` and `Set` if more dates have to be accommodated :-

```js
const data = [
  {date: "2021-04-09T12:00",duration: 1,available: 1,booked: 0,product_id: 2390,date_format: "PM"},
  {date: "2021-04-09T22:00",duration: 1,available: 1,booked: 0,product_id: 2390,date_format: "PM"},
  {date: "2021-04-10T2:00",duration: 1,available: 1,booked: 0,product_id: 2390,date_format: "PM"},
  {date: "2021-04-10T22:00",duration: 1,available: 1,booked: 0,product_id: 2390,date_format: "AM"},
  {date: "2021-05-09T22:00",duration: 1,available: 1,booked: 0,product_id: 2390,date_format: "AM"},
]

const dates = ["2021-04-09"];


function transform(data,dates){

const dateSet = new Set(dates);

const transformedOutput = data.reduce((output,curr)=>{
    const [date,time] = curr.date.split('T');
    if(dateSet.has(date))
    {
      output.push({...curr,date:time})
    }
     return output;
},[])
return transformedOutput;
}

console.log(transform(data,dates));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired result using the reduce function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

```
const dateFilter = "2021-04-09";

const apiResponse = [
  { date: "2021-04-09T12:00", duration: 1, available: 1, booked: 0, product_id: 2390, date_format: "PM" },
  { date: "2021-04-09T22:00", duration: 1, available: 1, booked: 0, product_id: 2390, date_format: "PM" },
  { date: "2021-04-10T2:00", duration: 1, available: 1, booked: 0, product_id: 2390, date_format: "PM" },
  { date: "2021-04-10T22:00", duration: 1, available: 1, booked: 0, product_id: 2390, date_format: "AM" }
];

const filteredResponse = apiResponse.reduce((a, b) => {
  if (b.date.startsWith(dateFilter)) {
    a.push({
      ...b,
      date: b.date.replace(`${dateFilter}T`, '')
    });
  }
  return a;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use moment js package to convert date of any format to time , code for it is

```
const data=[
  {date: "2021-04-09T12:00",duration: 1,available: 1,booked: 0,product_id: 2390,date_format: "PM"},
  {date: "2021-04-09T22:00",duration: 1,available: 1,booked: 0,product_id: 2390,date_format: "PM"},
  {date: "2021-04-10T2:00",duration: 1,available: 1,booked: 0,product_id: 2390,date_format: "PM"},
  {date: "2021-04-10T22:00",duration: 1,available: 1,booked: 0,product_id: 2390,date_format: "AM"},
]


const formatTime = data.map((item) => {
  return {...item,date:moment(item.date).format("LT")}
});

formatTime(data)
```

you can check this sand box for ref

[image: Edit weathered-wave-70f6j]

Answer (score 0):

you can use this without using moment.js

```
let date_groups = [
    { date: "2021-04-09T12:00", duration: 1, available: 1, booked: 0, product_id: 2390, date_format: "PM" },
    { date: "2021-04-09T22:00", duration: 1, available: 1, booked: 0, product_id: 2390, date_format: "PM" },
    { date: "2021-04-10T2:00", duration: 1, available: 1, booked: 0, product_id: 2390, date_format: "PM" },
    { date: "2021-04-10T22:00", duration: 1, available: 1, booked: 0, product_id: 2390, date_format: "AM" },
  ]

  let date_filter = '2021-04-09'

  let time_group = date_groups
    .filter(date_group => date_group.date.includes(date_filter))
    .map(date_group => {
      let time_divider = date_group.date.indexOf('T') + 1
      return { ...date_group, date: date_group.date.substring(time_divider, date_group.date.length) }
    })
```